# Как выровнять select option?

Tags: html, css, html-select

Можно ли выровнять option в select как то ? Что бы окно было статическое например, не выпрыгивало выше селкекта, а например только снизу. Это вообще возможно ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно, если не стандартным селектом а плагином каким-нибудь (типа select2 например)

Answer (score 1):

Стандартный `select` очень плохо поддается стилизации, лучше использовать кастомный и уже самому определять направление, анимацию и многое другое. Например `div` вместо `select` и `span` вместо `option`.

Или через `label` и `input type="radio"`:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: monospace;
}


/* Selects */


/* General Select */

label.selectGeneral {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 2px 0;
  border: 3px solid #d6d6d6;
  border-radius: 0;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

label.selectGeneral:before {
  content: attr(placeholder);
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 34px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 34px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #adadad;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

label.selectGeneral:after {
  content: "<>";
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 31px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #d6d6d6;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

label.selectGeneral label {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 34px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 34px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

label.selectGeneral input,
label.selectGeneral label {
  display: none;
}

label.selectGeneral div {
  min-width: 100%;
  max-height: 500px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

label.selectGeneral input[type="radio"]:checked~div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 34px;
  z-index: 999;
  overflow-y: auto;
  box-shadow: -3px 0 0 #d6d6d6, 3px 0 0 #d6d6d6;
  border-top: 3px solid #d6d6d6;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #d6d6d6;
}

label.selectGeneral input[type="radio"]:checked~div>label,
label.selectGeneral input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
  display: block;
}

label.selectGeneral input[type="radio"]:checked~div>label:hover {
  background-color: #ffa834;
}

label.selectGeneral input[type="radio"]:not(:checked)~div>input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<label class="selectGeneral" placeholder="select your OS...">
  <input type="radio" name="OS">
  <div>
     <input type="radio" name="OS" value="Linux" id="OS[Linux]">
     <label for="OS[Linux]">linux</label>
     <input type="radio" name="OS" value="Windows" id="OS[Windows]">
     <label for="OS[Windows]">windows</label>
     <input type="radio" name="OS" value="Other" id="OS[Other]">
     <label for="OS[Other]">other</label>
     </div>
</label>
```

[Источник](https://habrahabr.ru/post/248243/)

Comment: **[Почему и как удаляются некоторые ответы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)**

Comment: почему - вопрос риторический, как - у автора есть возможность редактировать или удалить свое сообщение.

Comment: если отвечаете, то ответ не должен быть только ссылкой на другой ресурс.  **[как публиковать ответы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)**

Comment: Это больше комментарий, чем ответ...

Comment: Возможно Вы не поняли сути комментариев. Ссылка - это тоже неплохо и Вы правильно ее указали. **Но!** Для полноценного ответа Вам **нужно было перенести важную часть из ссылки в ответ**, т.к. ссылка на другом ресурсе может быть недоступной со временем и указать ссылку как источник. В Вашем случае по ссылке вся полезная информация - это рабочий код и именно его Вам и нужно было добавить в свой ответ. Обновили Ваш ответ, посмотрите пожалуйста как он должен выглядеть. Если редакция Вашего ответа Вас не устраивает по какой-либо причине, откатите ее.